# SQL query for setting column based on last seven entries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

## Problem

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a query that can tell if any userentry is preceded by 7 days without any activity (secondsPlayed == 0) and if so, then indicate it with the value of 1, otherwise 0.

This also means that if the user has less than 7 entries, the value will be 0 across all entries.

```
Input table:
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|            userid            |     estimationDate      | secondsPlayed |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| a                            | 2016-07-14 00:00:00 UTC | 192.5         |
| a                            | 2016-07-15 00:00:00 UTC | 357.3         |
| a                            | 2016-07-16 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-17 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-18 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-19 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-20 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-21 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-22 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-23 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| a                            | 2016-07-24 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| ---------------------------- | ----------------------  | ----          |
| b                            | 2016-07-02 00:00:00 UTC | 31.2          |
| b                            | 2016-07-03 00:00:00 UTC | 42.1          |
| b                            | 2016-07-04 00:00:00 UTC | 41.9          |
| b                            | 2016-07-05 00:00:00 UTC | 43.2          |
| b                            | 2016-07-06 00:00:00 UTC | 91.5          |
| b                            | 2016-07-07 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| b                            | 2016-07-08 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
| b                            | 2016-07-09 00:00:00 UTC | 239.1         |
| b                            | 2016-07-10 00:00:00 UTC | 0             |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

The intended output table should look like this:

```
Output table:

+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+----------+
|            userid            |     estimationDate      | secondsPlayed | inactive |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+----------+
| a                            | 2016-07-14 00:00:00 UTC | 192.5         | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-15 00:00:00 UTC | 357.3         | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-16 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-17 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-18 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-19 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-20 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-21 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| a                            | 2016-07-22 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 1        |
| a                            | 2016-07-23 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 1        |
| a                            | 2016-07-24 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 1        |
| ---------------------------- | ----------------------- | -----         | -----    |
| b                            | 2016-07-02 00:00:00 UTC | 31.2          | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-03 00:00:00 UTC | 42.1          | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-04 00:00:00 UTC | 41.9          | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-05 00:00:00 UTC | 43.2          | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-06 00:00:00 UTC | 91.5          | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-07 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-08 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-09 00:00:00 UTC | 239.1         | 0        |
| b                            | 2016-07-10 00:00:00 UTC | 0             | 0        |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+----------+
```

### Thoughts

At first I was thinking about using the Lag function with a 7 offset, but this would obviously not relate to any of the subjects in between.

I was also thinking about creating a rolling window/average for a period of 7 days and evaluating if this is above 0. However this might be a bit above my skill level.

Any chance anyone has a good solution to this problem.

Comment: "This also means that if the user has less than 7 entries, the value will be 1 across all entries." . . . Your sample results do not support this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Gee! I actually meant 0, I will change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have data every day (which seems like a reasonable assumption), you can sum a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(secondsplayed) over (partition by userid
                                           order by estimationdate
                                           rows between 6 preceding and current row
                                          ) = 0 and
                  row_number() over (partition by userid order by estimationdate) >= 7
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as inactive                  
from t;
```

In addition to no holes in the dates, this also assumes that `secondsplayed` is never negative.  (Negative values can easily be incorporated into the logic, but that seems unnecessary.)

Comment: And if you don't have data for every day, you can always force it. Calendar Tables to the rescue again! :-)

Comment: @Shawn . . . If data is not available for all 7 days, then I would switch to using `range between`.  That doesn't seem necessary for the data provided by the OP, so it seems like an  unnecessary complication.

Comment: I'm off to bed, but this solution looks correct! I'm looking forward to giving it a spin! :-)

Comment: I tred running this @GordonLinoff, however it did not work in Google BigQuery as it threw the following error:
'Error: Encountered " "OVER" "over "" at line 2, column 27. Was expecting: "THEN" ...' Presumably it may be due to an analytical function being side of an CASE statement as presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842368/bigquery-error-encountered-over-over) however, I am not sure if I can apply the same solution as they do.

Comment: @ThomasHeiberg . . . Are you sure you are using standard SQL?  I don't have a problem using window functions in `case` expressions.

Comment: I did indeed not use standard SQL, after doing so, this solved my problem! Thank you so much @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2):

In my experience this type of input tables do not consist of inactivity entries and usually look like this (only activity entries are present here)

```
Input table:
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|            userid            |     estimationDate      | secondsPlayed |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| a                            | 2016-07-14 00:00:00 UTC | 192.5         |
| a                            | 2016-07-15 00:00:00 UTC | 357.3         |
| ---------------------------- | ----------------------  | ----          |
| b                            | 2016-07-02 00:00:00 UTC | 31.2          |
| b                            | 2016-07-03 00:00:00 UTC | 42.1          |
| b                            | 2016-07-04 00:00:00 UTC | 41.9          |
| b                            | 2016-07-05 00:00:00 UTC | 43.2          |
| b                            | 2016-07-06 00:00:00 UTC | 91.5          |
| b                            | 2016-07-09 00:00:00 UTC | 239.1         |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

So, below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and input as above

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' userid, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-14 00:00:00 UTC' estimationDate, 192.5 secondsPlayed UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', '2016-07-15 00:00:00 UTC', 357.3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-07-02 00:00:00 UTC', 31.2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-07-03 00:00:00 UTC', 42.1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-07-04 00:00:00 UTC', 41.9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-07-05 00:00:00 UTC', 43.2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-07-06 00:00:00 UTC', 91.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-07-09 00:00:00 UTC', 239.1 
), time_frame AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2016-07-02', '2016-07-24')) day
)
SELECT 
  users.userid, 
  day, 
  IFNULL(secondsPlayed, 0) secondsPlayed,
  CAST(1 - SIGN(SUM(IFNULL(secondsPlayed, 0)) 
    OVER(
      PARTITION BY users.userid 
      ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(day)
      RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    )) AS INT64) AS inactive 
FROM time_frame tf
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM `project.dataset.table`) users
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON day = DATE(estimationDate) AND users.userid = t.userid
ORDER BY userid, day
```

with result

```
  
Row userid  day         secondsPlayed   inactive     
...
13  a       2016-07-14  192.5           0    
14  a       2016-07-15  357.3           0    
15  a       2016-07-15  357.3           0    
16  a       2016-07-16  0.0             0    
17  a       2016-07-17  0.0             0    
18  a       2016-07-18  0.0             0    
19  a       2016-07-19  0.0             0    
20  a       2016-07-20  0.0             0    
21  a       2016-07-21  0.0             0    
22  a       2016-07-22  0.0             1    
23  a       2016-07-23  0.0             1    
24  a       2016-07-24  0.0             1    
25  b       2016-07-02  31.2            0    
26  b       2016-07-03  42.1            0    
27  b       2016-07-04  41.9            0    
28  b       2016-07-05  43.2            0    
29  b       2016-07-06  91.5            0    
30  b       2016-07-07  0.0             0    
31  b       2016-07-08  0.0             0    
32  b       2016-07-09  239.1           0    
33  b       2016-07-10  0.0             0    
...
```